# Customize keyboard layout FM (Delphi XE5) Mobile

Tags: delphi, keyboard, customization

Is there a way to customize a (or create a new) KeyboardType for mobile devices (iOS and Android)?

I've found different questions, however not one was related to FireMonkey (Delphi XE5).

Required is that the layout is numeric and has a '+' and '-' button.